# Resample Pandas Dataframe Without Filling in Missing Times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-resample

Resampling a dataframe can take the dataframe to either a higher or lower temporal resolution.  Most of the time this is used to go to lower resolution (e.g. resample 1-minute data to monthly values).  When the dataset is sparse (for example, no data were collected in Feb-2020) then the Feb-2020 row in will be filled with NaNs the resampled dataframe.  The problem is when the data record is long AND sparse there are a lot of NaN rows, which makes the dataframe unnecessarily large and takes a lot of CPU time.  For example, consider this dataframe and resample operation:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

freq1 = pd.date_range("20000101", periods=10, freq="S")
freq2 = pd.date_range("20200101", periods=10, freq="S")

index = np.hstack([freq1.values, freq2.values])
data = np.random.randint(0, 100, (20, 10))
cols = list("ABCDEFGHIJ")

df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, data=data, columns=cols)

# now resample to daily average
df = df.resample(rule="1D").mean()
```

Most of the data in this dataframe is useless and can be removed via:

```
df.dropna(how="all", axis=0, inplace=True)
```

however, this is sloppy.  Is there another method to resample the dataframe that does not fill all of the data gaps with NaN (i.e. in the example above, the resultant dataframe would have only two rows)?

Answer (score 9):

*Updating my original answer with (what I think) is an improvement, plus updated times.*

#### Use `groupby`

There are a couple ways you can use `groupby` instead of `resample`.  In the case of a day (`"1D"`) resampling, you can just use the `date` property of the `DateTimeIndex`:

```
df = df.groupby(df.index.date).mean()
```

This is in fact faster than the `resample` for your data:

```
%%timeit
df.resample(rule='1D').mean().dropna()
# 2.08 ms ± 114 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
df.groupby(df.index.date).mean()
# 666 µs ± 15.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

The more general approach would be to use the floor of the timestamps to do the `groupby` operation:

```
rule = '1D'
f = df.index.floor(rule)
df.groupby(f).mean()

#                A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H     I     J
# 2000-01-01  50.5  33.5  62.7  42.4  46.7  49.2  64.0  53.3  71.0  38.0
# 2020-01-01  50.4  56.3  57.4  46.2  55.0  60.2  60.3  57.8  63.5  47.3
```

This will work with more irregular frequencies as well.  The main snag here is that by default, it seems like the floor is calculated in reference to some initial date, which can cause weird results ([see my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62822739/how-to-set-the-base-of-a-datetime-floor-operation-in-pandas)):

```
rule = '7D'
f = df.index.floor(rule)
df.groupby(f).mean()

#                A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H     I     J
# 1999-12-30  50.5  33.5  62.7  42.4  46.7  49.2  64.0  53.3  71.0  38.0
# 2019-12-26  50.4  56.3  57.4  46.2  55.0  60.2  60.3  57.8  63.5  47.3
```

The major issue is that the resampling doesn't start on the earliest timestamp within your data.  However, it is fixable using [this solution to the above post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62823802/13386979):

```
# custom function for flooring relative to a start date
def floor(x, freq):
    offset = x[0].ceil(freq) - x[0]
    return (x + offset).floor(freq) - offset

rule = '7D'
f = floor(df.index, rule)
df.groupby(f).mean()

#                A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H     I     J
# 2000-01-01  50.5  33.5  62.7  42.4  46.7  49.2  64.0  53.3  71.0  38.0
# 2019-12-28  50.4  56.3  57.4  46.2  55.0  60.2  60.3  57.8  63.5  47.3

# the cycle of 7 days is now starting from 01-01-2000
```

Just note here that the function `floor()` is relatively slow compared to `pandas.Series.dt.floor()`.  So it is best to us the latter if you can, but both are better than the original `resample` (in your example):

```
%%timeit
df.groupby(df.index.floor('1D')).mean()
# 1.06 ms ± 6.52 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit
df.groupby(floor(df.index, '1D')).mean()
# 1.42 ms ± 14.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: While good for 1D frequencies I really want something more flexible that allows different resample frequencies.  That being said, I didn't know I can specify df.index.date in groupby so thanks for the tip.

Comment: @tnknepp If you are still interested, see my updated answer.  There is a more general approach using `floor` which seems to be faster.

Comment: In case it may help to anyone: in an `xarray` `da` with a `time` dimension you can apply `f` as `f = da.time.dt.floor("1D")`.

Comment: (It will rename your `time` dimension to `floor`, though).