# Pandas GroupBy without filling in missing data

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a file of half-hourly data which I wish to group together by hour. This works:

```
data.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1h')).agg('sum')
```

However, it fills in hours where there is no half-hourly data.

How can I perform a grouping like this but not create records where there was no data in the input DataFrame? e.g. From:

```
07:00
07:30
09:00
09:30
```

I want to create:

```
07:00
09:00
```

Not:

```
07:00
08:00
09:00
```

Thanks

Comment: You can always filter out rows after getting your result:

    `result = result[result.index.isin(data.index)]` Don't think there's a way to do that with `groupby` directly.

Comment: you can round down to the hour then drop duplicates keeping the first value, can you post some sample of your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to filter out the added times, you can do what cs95 said in the comments or:

```
out = data.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1h')).sum(min_count=1).dropna()
```

The `min_count` makes NaN be the output if there is no data for the bin, which can then be removed with `dropna()`.

If you instead don't want those extra bins to be *computed in the first place*, this can be more complicated (Note that there is a similar [open post on this, also from today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62817920/resample-pandas-dataframe-without-filling-in-missing-times/62818447#62818447)).  But given an hourly bin frequency, you can do something like this:

```
out1 = data.groupby(data.index.hour).sum()
```

And if the data span multiple days, you could do:

```
out2 = data.groupby([data.index.date, data.index.hour]).sum()
```

But note here that the data index is out of `datetime` format now, so you might need to convert back.

Here's the example data I used:

```
import pandas as pd

dr = pd.date_range('1-1-2020 7:00', periods=6, freq='30min')
data = pd.DataFrame([10,20,30,40,50,60], index=dr, columns=['Values'])
data = data[data.index.hour != 8]
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you very much.