# Pandas resample only when makes sense

Tags: pandas, pandas-resample

I have a time series that is very irregular. The difference in time, between two records can be 1s or 10 days.

I want to resample the data every 1h, but only when the sequential records are less than 1h.

How to approach this, without making too many loops?

In the example above, I would like to resample only rows 5-6 (delta difference is 10s) and rows 6-7 (delta difference is 50min).
The others should remain as they are.

```
tmp=vals[['datumtijd','filter data']]

     datumtijd           filter data
0   1970-11-01 00:00:00        129.0
1   1970-12-01 00:00:00        143.0
2   1971-01-05 00:00:00        151.0
3   1971-02-01 00:00:00        151.0
4   1971-03-01 00:00:00        163.0
5   1971-03-01 00:00:10        163.0
6   1971-03-01 00:00:20        163.0
7   1971-03-01 00:01:10        163.0
8   1971-03-01 00:04:10        163.0
..         ...          ...
244 1981-08-19 00:00:00        102.0
245 1981-09-02 00:00:00         98.0
246 1981-09-17 00:00:00         92.0
247 1981-10-01 00:00:00         89.0
248 1981-10-19 00:00:00         92.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be a little explicit about this by using `groupby` on the hour-floor of the time stamps:

```
grouped = df.groupby(df['datumtijd'].dt.floor('1H')).mean()
```

This is explicitly looking for the hour of each *existing* data point and grouping the matching ones.

But you can also just do the resample and then filter out the empty data, as `pandas` can still do this pretty quickly:

```
resampled = df.resample('1H', on='datumtijd').mean().dropna()
```

In either case, you get the following (note that I changed the last time stamp just so that the console would show the hours):

```
                     filter data
datumtijd                       
1970-11-01 00:00:00        129.0
1970-12-01 00:00:00        143.0
1971-01-05 00:00:00        151.0
1971-02-01 00:00:00        151.0
1971-03-01 00:00:00        163.0
1981-08-19 00:00:00        102.0
1981-09-02 00:00:00         98.0
1981-09-17 00:00:00         92.0
1981-10-01 00:00:00         89.0
1981-10-19 03:00:00         92.0
```

One quick clarification also.  In your example, rows 5-8 all occur within the same hour, so they all get grouped together (hour:minute:second)!.

Also, see this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62817920/resample-pandas-dataframe-without-filling-in-missing-times/62818447#62818447).